# How to run remote scripts in windows machine using azure pipeline and teams

Tags: azure, azure-devops

How to run remote scripts in windows machine using azure pipeline and Microsoft teams

Comment: Please explain more of your context. What does Teams have to do with running scripts via pipelines?

Answer (score 0):

> How to run remote scripts in windows machine using azure pipeline and
> teams

## 1, For Teams

If the teams you mentioned is the product 'Microsoft Teams', then **the answer is NO**.

Microsoft Teams will not have any relationship with run scripts in pipeline by default.

See the official document:

[Use Azure Pipelines with Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/integrations/microsoft-teams?view=azure-devops)

[Available commands in Azure Pipelines app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/integrations/microsoft-teams?view=azure-devops#use-commands-in-azure-pipelines-app)

[image]

As you can see, no commands in this app can achieve your requirement.

And, Azure pipeline app was started from 2019, the original intention of the design is mainly for monitor the pipelines:

[Azure Pipelines app on Microsoft Teams enables you to monitor the events for your pipelines.](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams-blog/new-azure-pipelines-app-for-microsoft-teams/ba-p/645225)

Official app of azure pipeline doesn't support your requirements. If you want trigger your pipeline from Teams, I think you need to design your own app, the related technology should be this:

[Webhooks and connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/what-are-webhooks-and-connectors)

The trigger type will be 'Manually trigger' in this situation.

## 2, For Azure pipeline

There are two ways.

1, First way is to [set up a self-hosted agent on remote windows machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops), after that, run the devops pipeline based on the agent pool that the agent you set up on.

2, Second way is to use prepared tasks in azure DevOps pipeline and turn on related protocols in remote machine. After that, you will be able to do anything on remote machine.

Tasks to achieve this requirement:

[SSH@0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/ssh-v0?view=azure-pipelines)

[PowerShellOnTargetMachines@3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/powershell-on-target-machines-v3?view=azure-pipelines)